# mac - pip install pymssql error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pymssql

I use Mac (OS X 10.11.5). I want to install module `pymssql` for python.
In `Terminal.app`, I input `sudo -H pip install pymssql`, `pip install pymssql`, `sudo pip install pymssql` . But error occur.

> The directory `/Users/janghyunsoo/Library/Caches/pip/http` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing `pip` with `sudo`, you may want `sudo`'s `-H` flag.
>
> The directory `/Users/janghyunsoo/Library/Caches/pip` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing `pip` with `sudo`, you may want `sudo`'s `-H` flag.

```
Collecting pymssql
  Downloading pymssql-2.1.2.tar.gz (898kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 901kB 955kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-KA5ksi/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-A3wRBy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Darwin'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', '')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('', '')
    setup.py: Detected Darwin/Mac OS X.
        You can install FreeTDS with Homebrew or MacPorts, or by downloading
        and compiling it yourself.
    
        Homebrew (http://brew.sh/)
        --------------------------
        brew install freetds
    
        MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/)
        -----------------------------------
        sudo port install freetds
    
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/opt/local/include', '/opt/local/include/freetds']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building '_mssql' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetds -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
    _mssql.c:18924:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBVERSION_80'
        __pyx_r = DBVERSION_80;
                  ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-KA5ksi/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-A3wRBy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-KA5ksi/pymssql/
```

Comment: Any solution yet? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Every time I use pip, there is at least one error. Every time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was able to work around this by reverting to an older version of FreeTDS through Homebrew before running the pip install.

```
brew unlink freetds; brew install homebrew/versions/freetds091
```

The solution was found by andrewmwhite at:
https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/432

Comment: Worked perfectly on os x el capitan 10.11.5

Comment: Homebrew/versions is now deprecated but answer below works great.

Answer (score 60):

The top voted solution did not work for me as brew did not link the older version of freetds on its own. I did this to solve the problem:

```
brew unlink freetds; 
brew install freetds@0.91;
brew link --force freetds@0.91
```

Comment: Solved it for me with python 3.6. Thank you!

Comment: Solved my problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: Worked for me on macOS high sierra with python 3.6 except that I had to manually remove freetds.conf, locales.conf, pool.conf under /usr/local/etc/ before "brew link --force freetds@0.91"

Answer (score 5):

Found Detailed and simple answer with step by step installation of pymssql on http://gree2.github.io/python/setup/2017/04/19/python-instal-pymssql-on-mac.

1. `brew unlink freetds; brew install homebrew/core/freetds091`
2. `brew link --force freetds@0.91`
3. `pip install pymssql`

Answer (score 2):

### Found a solution for pip/python2 & pip3/python3

### Problem:

I was Unable to get a successful build from pip3 following @siva & @himanshu workaround works for `python2` but not for `python3`.

```
pip3 install pymssql

    ..._mssql.c:21155:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBVERSION_80'
        __pyx_r = DBVERSION_80;
                  ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Your issue is not a permission issue, but, a code-compiling issue with dependent code for `pymssql`.

[Here's the discussion](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/432), 
Where I found the [Solution on github.](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/543)

> It has been around for a while at this point, just placing here for visibility.

Just use the newest build of pymssql from gitub:

```
    pip3 install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql
```

Also works for python2

```
    pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql
```

**OR**

```
    pip2 install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql
```

I Tested on `Mac OS X (10.13.6) & Homebrew (1.7.1-62-gddbefee)` multiple times.
The command works for both versions of freetds (0.91) or (1.00.94)

Answer (score 1):

"brew install homebrew/python/pymssql" also worked but will install older 2.1.1 as of today.

Comment: FYI - has historically known conflicts with Anaconda or `conda` not sure if all of them have been resolved but noting here incase someone runs into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on mac:

```
pip install cython
```

then

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql.git
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions above work well . Just one word of caution , the  `setup.py` for **pymssql** `pip install pymssql` expects that Homebrew has installed Freetds at **/sw** on your machine.

This was not the case in my machine so I had to use the work around here :

1. Manually download the .tar file for pymssql
2. Open  **setup.py**
3. Edit the variable **fink** to add the path to  where ever Freetds is actually installed on your machine.

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
     fink = '<path to Freetds on your Machine>'
```

3. Then run `python setup.py install`