# Connecting to a SQL db using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I currently have a python script that can connect to a mySQL db and execute queries.  I wish to modify it so that I can connect to a different SQL db to run a separate query.  I am having trouble doing this, running osx 10.11.  This is my first question and I'm a newbie programmer so please take it easy on me...

Here is the program i used to for mySQL

```
sf_username = "user"
sf_password = "pass"
sf_api_token = "token"

sf_update = beatbox.PythonClient()
 password = str("%s%s" % (sf_password, sf_api_token))
sf_update.login(sf_username, password)

t = Terminal()

hub = [stuff]

def FINAL_RUN():
    cnx = alternate_modify(hub)
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    queryinput = """
    SQL QUERY I WANT
    """
    cur.execute(queryinput)
    rez = cur.fetchone()
    while rez is not None:
        write_to_sf(rez)
        rez = cur.fetchone()

FINAL_RUN()
```

Comment: It will be much easier to you (as long as you're _newbee_ as you said) not to deal with some generic case, but to ask more specific question.
As long as, for example, handling MsSQL/PostgreSQL/Oracle may differ lot in a short while after to connect to it

Comment: You could always check the database you're storing to and execute different SQL queries depending on the database. Or, you could use an ORM like SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Python library called SQLAlchemy. It abstracts away the "low-level" operations you would do with a database (e.g. specifying queries manually).

A tutorial for using SQLAlchemy can be found [here](http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get connected using SQL Alchemy--thank you.  If anyone else tries, I think you'll need a ODBC driver per this page:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html

Alternatively, pymssql is a nice tool.  If you run into trouble installing like I did, there is a neat workaround here:

[mac - pip install pymssql error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771434/mac-pip-install-pymssql-error)

Thanks again