# FreeTDS configuration on MacOS without .so files

Tags: python, odbc, freetds, pypyodbc, iodbc

Can anyone point me to how to setup an ODBC connection to a MS SQL Server using FreeTDS? All of the posts and items I found on the web so far require the .so file which is no longer generated (or required) when installing FreeTDS according to its [documentation](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#where.is.libtds.so). What confuses me is the fact that the user documentation also shows a setup using the libtdsodbc.so file.

I did manage to find this link on Github (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/24550) about someone who manually compiled iODBC for Mac and got it working, but after cloning the corresponding Guthub iODBC source I wasn't able to compile it without errors. Error 127 (which is what I get) is rather vague for me. The manual install of iODBC somehow made `brew install freetds` find the required iODBC headers to generate libtdsodbc.so.

I assume since FreeTDS no longer generates any .so (Shared Object), it is supposed to function without them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Andre.

Comment: I'd suggest installing the latest [precompiled iODBC for OS X (currently 3.52.12)](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X). OS X builds often use `.dylib` instead of `.so`; the files are the same. ["Free" ODBC drivers often cost more in time than you save in cash](http://www.openlinksw.com/weblogs/uda/?id=1847)...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround it here in Stackflow by using an older version of FreeTDS and pymssql:
[mac - pip install pymssql error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771434/mac-pip-install-pymssql-error)

Now on to the next challenge. :)

Cheers!!